# I'm having trouble using setProperty() to set CSS variable for background-image url

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working on creating a React component for a range slider where the slider thumb is an image that changes at certain values along the slider bar.

I attempted to do this with CSS classes, by changing the classes at certain values and each class is assigned an image from a local image folder. This worked great, but I had to create a class for each one of the values that I have an image for. Not too big of a deal if you only have a few images to use, but I'd like to have the option of adding many more images.

So I figured I'd give CSS variables a shot and change the image url with javascript. I was able to get something working for `background-color`, but not for `background-image` which is what I'm really looking to change.

I am able to set the CSS variable for background-image and background-color...

```
:root {
  --background-image: url('./Smileys/smiley4.png');
  --background-color: red;
}
```

...and set the background-image and background-color here

```
background-image: var(--background-image);
background-color: var(--background-color);
```

And it will set the correct image when the slider is first loaded, but when I move the slider, the image disappears and no new image is set. The color works fine.

This is the javascript I'm attempting to use.

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background-image', 'url("./Smileys/smiley2.png")')
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background-color', 'green')
```

I have tried a lot different variations with the quotes in all sorts of different places for the url. I've tried numerous jQuery and concatenation options, but have really struck out.

I can't figure out why it works for background-color, but not background-image.

I should note that there are five images in the image folder and the only difference is the number in the name `smiley1.png` `smiley2.png` etc. I've double and triple checked all of my paths. Quadruple check might be in order, but I don't think so.

I appreciate any help I can get. I'm definitely open to going a completely different direction, but I started down this path and would like to figure out a solution, if at all possible.

**UPDATE**

I was able to make a little progress, but it is still not making a lot of sense to me yet.

I logged the initial url that I was setting

```
const el = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--background-image')
    console.log(el)
```

And got this back...
`url(\/static\/media\/smiley4\.e2025ea6\.png)`

Sooo, I tried adding this line into the my javascript like so

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background-image', 'url(\/static\/media\/smiley4\.e2025ea6\.png)')
```

and it worked!! Although, it's not really a great solution because now I have to type out each and every url in it's entirety.

I was hoping to name all the images similarly with the exception of a number value and have them change based on the value. Something like this.

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background-image', 'url({`smiley${number}.png`)')
```

**UPDATE2**

Thanks to [kenput3r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8074949/kenput3r) I ended up importing the images from my image folder and then creating an array for the images.

```
const number = Math.round(event.target.value)

    const smileys = ['', smiley1, smiley2, smiley3, smiley4, smiley5]

    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background-image', `url(${smileys[number]})`)
```

I still want to work on refactoring it a bit so I won't have to create the array, but I think this pretty much solves my problem. Thanks to everyone for helping me out.

This [Link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) on adding images, fonts and files was definitely helpful.

[Here is the slider](https://gmorse19.github.io/HappySlider/)

Comment: Have you tried setting only the path as a custom property and then use it like `background-image: url(var(--background-image-path))`? Not sure if that will help though. And you should really try to minimize the code on the question, there's a lot of code, probably most of it is not needed to show your problem. You should post a minimal sample code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I did try a couple different variations of that, but I think I'll give it another shot. Sorry for all the code! I'll cut it down some.

Comment: [Can't repro](https://jsfiddle.net/2edx5m81/) Can you check the network panel of your dev-tools to see if the resource are gathered?

Comment: Thanks for the very clear breakdown. Are you using a static site generator? You might be able to import the images into variables instead of typing out those long static paths. Only thing that I can think of is that the relative path only works the first time because the full path is generated at build time.

Comment: @Kaiido I checked the network panel. When the page first loads it shows the image with a type of 'text/plain' after moving the slider, the image does not show and the type is 'text/html'. Not sure if that helps. I'm not very adept with the dev tools just yet.

Comment: `text/plain` is weird, and `text/html` is certainly a 404 error page. Can you try to go to the page that the browser tried to load (right click from the network panel on the url-> Open in new tab)

Comment: @kenput3r Thanks for the answer. I am not using a static site generator. I'm not sure how I could import them into variables, but I'd be willing to try!!

Comment: Right clicked and opened another page. I get the same result with a status of 304.

Comment: The name does change, though. The initial image that actually works is named `smiley.f3969dab.png` and the one that doesn't work is `smiley.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relative paths don't work after the build.

Import your images like below, and use the variables for the `src`

Docs here [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

```
import smiley1 from './Smileys/smiley1.png`;
import smiley2 from './Smileys/smiley2.png`;
import smiley3 from './Smileys/smiley3.png`;
import smiley4 from './Smileys/smiley4.png`;

document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--background-image`, `url(${smiley1})`);
```

If you want to access them by index, you could always just put them in an array:

```
const smileys = [smiley1, smiley2, smiley3, smiley4];
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--background-image`, `url(${smileys[0]})`);
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you. I tried both ways and they both work. I opted for the index version, for now. I never would have thought to import them in that way. So much to learn! Thanks again.